# Can´t extract the pagination link with scrapy

Tags: python, pagination, scrapy

I want to identify the "next-page-link" with and for scrapy of a multi page website. 
I have the feeling that I cannot do it the common way as the href-content is empty (href=""). See here:

```
<div class="publicusers-page-navigation page-navigation">
<a href="" class="current" data-page-index="1">1</a>
<a href="" data-page-index="2">2</a><a href="" data-page-index="3">3</a>
<i>...</i>
<a href="" data-page-index="330">330</a>
<a href="" class="pagination-next" data-page-index="2">►</a>
</div>
```

I tried 
    `response.css('div.page-navigation > a::attr(href)').extract_first()`

but it's not working.

I´d appreciate if someone could help me as I´m struggeling with this problem already for a while.

Comment: `href` attribute of that `<a>` node is empty. This means the pagination is most likely javascript generated. Could you post the website you are crawling?

Comment: https://www.vdma.org/mitglieder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply generate the urls, then parse.

```
page = 0
for i in range(330):
    page+=1
    url = ('https://www.vdma.org/mitglieder'
        '?p_p_lifecycle=2&p_p_resource_id=getPage&p_p_id'
        '=vdma2publicusers_WAR_vdma2publicusers&s=&page='+str(page))
    print(url)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! How is it possible to generate these? Where do you have this url from?

Comment: Do inspect element and check network for POST and GET